# SignalR 2 Startup Trouble

Tags: signalr, owin, katana

Trying to launch simple windows forms SignalR server, but when I get into WebApp.Start(URL) debug just disattaches with no errors and server not working.

How do I debug signalR and why server is not working?

CODE:

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace MessengerServer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        const string URL = "http://localhost:8080";

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebApp.Start<Startup>(URL);
            richTextBox1.AppendText("Server running on " + URL);            
        }
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }

    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you creating your hub?

Comment: Self-hosted based in windows forms application

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
private IDisposable SignalR { get; set; }
const string URL= "http://localhost:8080";

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   Task.Run(() => StartServer());
}

private void StartServer()
{
     try
     {
        SignalR = WebApp.Start(URL);
     }
     catch (TargetInvocationException)
     {

      }
      this.Invoke((Action)(() => richTextBox1.AppendText("Server running on " + URL)));

}
```

Comment: Now it threw me:An exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The server factory could not be located for the given input: Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener

Comment: if i continue it doesnt even execute code after exception handler block: this.Invoke((Action)(() => richTextBox1.AppendText("Server running on " + URL)));